# MySQL isn't returning the last month's data since we're in a new year

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME where dateSold <= '01/01/2021' and dateSold > '12/01/2020' and cardId = 'BZPcJP3eXaJLT3J' and ImageAccepted = 'accepted' order by dateSold asc
```

This will not return anything in the table, but there are entries, see image below.

[image]

Comment: What is the data type of `dateSold`?

Comment: What type of field is dateSold  and what is the version of your Server ?

Comment: dateSold is a varchar. @forpas

Comment: @MichealChoudhary im on godaddy, id have to hunt down the version of the server, but dateSold is a varchar.

Comment: Run following query and it will tell you the version:

Comment: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";

Comment: 5.6.49-cll-lve @MichealChoudhary

Comment: You should store dates in a date column, not varchar. Then they'll sort and filter like you expect. This column type exists for good reasons - use it.

Comment: if I was to change the structure of the column to a date or date and time, would that affect everything I have done already? all of queries for this database are exactly how I handle it above... I just noticed it because its a new year.

Comment: You might have to change some things yes, depending what you have done already, or at least test them. But it's the correct design decision and will benefit you overall, including helping to solve the problem you are asking about

Comment: Edit your Question with details rather than posting as comments.

Comment: Bluntly, either store dates using a proper date data type, or don't bother with an RDBMS.

Comment: This experience should be enough for you to change from varchar to proper date format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good pratise to use varChar for Date.

You can run following command on your current varChar field.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME where str_to_date(dateSold, '%m/%d/%Y') <= '01/01/2021' 
AND str_to_date(dateSold, '%m/%d/%Y') > '12/01/2020' 
AND cardId = 'BZPcJP3eXaJLT3J' 
AND ImageAccepted = 'accepted' 
ORDER BY date_format(str_to_date(dateSold, '%m/%d/%Y') ASC;
```

You can convert varChar data to Date by creating a new 'Date' field with default NULL and copy the data from 'dateSold' to the new field by running the folllowing command:

```
Update TABLE_NAME set dateNew = date(str_to_date(dateSol, '%m/%d/%Y'));
```

After running this command, remove Null from Default.

Comment: This answer starts well, and ends well. I'd remove the bit in the middle

Comment: PLEASE READ. 1) Create a new column and give it a date set type. The column will be created and display '0000-00-00' for each entry. 2) Run the second command and it will put dateSold into dateSoldNew as a date format. DO NOT change the original (dateSold) into a date, it will break things.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `date_sold` is a *date* data type then you would use:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE dateSold <= '2021-01-01' AND
      dateSold > '2020-01-01' AND
      cardId = 'BZPcJP3eXaJLT3J' AND 
      ImageAccepted = 'accepted' 
ORDER BY dateSold asc;
```

If it is not being stored as a date, then you should fix the data model.  In the meantime, you can use string operations.

```
WHERE dateSold LIKE '%-2020'
      cardId = 'BZPcJP3eXaJLT3J' AND 
      ImageAccepted = 'accepted' 
ORDER BY dateSold asc;
```

**Do not use string operations if the value is not stored as a string.**. Fix the data model so the value is stored using the correct data type.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `DATE` data type to store dates, because if you don't, like the the current case, you will have to convert the format `mm/dd/YYYY` to `DATE` first and then make comparisons to dates.
You will need the function [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(dateSold, '%m/%d/%Y') <= '2021-01-01' 
  AND STR_TO_DATE(dateSold, '%m/%d/%Y') > '2020-12-01' 
  AND cardId = 'BZPcJP3eXaJLT3J' 
  AND ImageAccepted = 'accepted' 
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(dateSold, '%m/%d/%Y') ASC
```

Comment: I get the following warning.. Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect date value: '01/02/2021', same for the other date. and nothing is returned.

Comment: Check this demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=38c15839eb140f63f2ebde9b24553984 to see that the code works. Did you copy the code as it is? Are you sure that all your dates have the same format?